# How can I assign a pci device to a ttyUSB port?

Tags: bash

I want to access the array containing the addresses of 2 pci devices. 
I want to assign the pci devices to a particular ttyUSB port that´s why i need to read out the address.
So how can I access the values of the array and assign it to a specific tty port?

> lspci | grep "[A-Za-z0-9]*:00.0[A-Za-z0-9 :]*Pericom[A-Za-z0-9 ]*400a[A-Za-z0-9 ()]*" | cut -c1-7

Please has anyone an idea how to get this work ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. In general, I think shell command questions that aren't specifically programming related should be posted instead on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com). In either case, it would help if you could post an example `lspci` output (without any unneeded identifiers) and what you expect to get from parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the output of a command into an array, you do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=($(lspci....))
```

then you can access the first element like this:

```
echo ${array[0]}
```

The number of elements in the array is:

```
${#array[@]}
```

And if you want to iterate over all members of the array:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#array[@]}; i++ ));
do
  echo ${array[$i]}
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I should have expressed myself more clear. My problem is that I don´t know which of the output values is [0],[1]...Let´s assume we have 3 addresses and I want a particular address of those 3 to be ttyUSB2. How can I assure that ${array[x]} is that address?

Comment: Probably with udevadm but I don't have a system available here. Maybe "udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB2"

Comment: Or maybe "udevadm info -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB2)"